# Path.GetTempFileName() - can I change this to use a shared drive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, file, temp

Using VS2008, c#.

When I call Path.GetTempFileName(), the temp file generated is something like:
C:\Users\allensamuel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC1D0.tmp

However, in the company I work, using the C: drive for files is not prohibited.  Rather, a login scrips points the user's "my documents" and "home" area (decouemtn and settings etc) are pointed to a networked "H:" drive.

I can't see why Path.GetTempFileName() is choosing the C: drive, or how to instruct it to use the H drive.

Any ideas?  I don't really want to create my own version ofthe above method.

Comment: You might find this handy... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx

Comment: Thank you - I am not yet on .Net 4, strange how they now put the environment variables in the remarks section for this version but not 3.5!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It chooses this path because it is set in `%TEMP%` environment variable. Try setting this variable to point somewhere around `H` drive.

Comment: +1  One would think that this would be set with some domain policy.

Comment: And when H: is networked (which OP claims it is) fileIOPermissions?

Comment: @rene, I believe it makes no difference whether it is network drive or not. If user has write permissions it should work fine, otherwise why OP would want that?

Comment: I was more referring to CodeAccessSecurity. Is H:\ considered a local drive and only unc paths like \\server\share are Network? OP is on 2.0 so the relaxed rules are not yet in place?

Comment: Thank you for this, I can confirm that %TEMP% is set to the C drive, and the .Net 4 documentation explicityly says that this env variable controls the behaviour of this method (thanks also to Ausin above).  I will check why this has happened because I can't think that our domain policy should be leaving this as the C drive.